# Custom Prefix to Livewire Components

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have created some LiveWire components in my Laravel Project and I want to add a custom prefix to these components.

Example.

I have a simple LiveWire component named `Button` created with `php artisan make:livewire Button`

It works fine when I use

```
<livewire:button />
```

but instead of `livewire:` prefix I want to use `components:` like this

```
<components:button />
```

I could not find any option for this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Best.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using Livewire for little components like this, that's not what Livewire is made for. Just create a standard Blade component instead

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Qirel, the Snippet I've given is just a sample, In project I am using some advanced components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be an officialy supported way to change the prefix of the Livewire components.

If I haven't completely misunderstood the code you could "hack" it by extending the [`LivewireTagCompiler`](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/master/src/LivewireTagCompiler.php) class and overwriting the `compileLivewireSelfClosingTags` method to use your own prefix. You'll then have to register it in any of your service providers' `boot` methods as the new precompiler of Blade.

```
$this->app['blade.compiler']->precompiler(function ($string) {
    return app(CustomLivewireTagCompiler::class)->compile($string);
});
```

It's a very ugly solution and could break if you are not careful and don't keep track of any changes made to the original class and I recommend just living with the `livewire:` prefix instead.

Comment: This worked, and as you suggested I will try and use `livewire:` prefix itself. 

Thank you so much for the help!!!